# How can I make ruby's xmlrpc client ignore SSL certificate errors?

Tags: ruby, ssl, xml-rpc

When access an XML-RPC service using `xmlrpc/client` in ruby, it throws an `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError` when the server certificate is not valid.  How can I make it ignore this error and proceed with the connection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out it's like this:

```
xmlrpc = ::XMLRPC::Client.new("foohost")
xmlrpc.instance_variable_get(:@http).instance_variable_set(:@verify_mode, OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
```

That works with ruby 1.9.2, but clearly is poking at internals, so the real answer is "the API doesn't provide such a mechanism, but here's a hack".

Answer (score 0):

Actually the client has been updated, now one has direct access to the http connection:
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/41286/diff/lib/xmlrpc/client.rb

```
xmlrpc.http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

But better set `ca_file` or `ca_path`.
Still I see no option to apply such config to `_async` calls.

Update: found a workaround by monkey patching the client object:

```
    xmlrpc_client.http.ca_file = @options[:ca_file]
    xmlrpc_client.instance_variable_set(:@ca_file, @options[:ca_file])
    def xmlrpc_client.net_http(host, port, proxy_host, proxy_port)
      h = Net::HTTP.new host, port, proxy_host, proxy_port
      h.ca_file = @ca_file
      h
    end
```

So you need both, the older approach and the monkey patching. We add also an instance variable, otherwise the new method cannot see the actual value.